# What is meant by "the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$"?

Tags: geometry, notation

I came across the following statement:

> The graph of $x^4 + y^4 = 1$ lies between the unit circle and the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$.

I have seen this type of $[x_1, y_1] \times [x_2, y_2]$ notation before, but I'm unsure what it means.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Comment: It's the closed set of points $(x,y)$ with both $|x|\le 1$ and $|y|\le 1$.

Comment: Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the square made of points $(x,y)$ such that $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $-1 \le y \le 1$

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would help to write $[x_1,x_2]\times [y_1,y_2]$. This represents the set of points $(x,y)$ with $x_1\le x\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y\le y_2$.